# Positioning an ActiveX Combobox in an Excel Document header

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have quite a simple question but cannot find a simple answer.

I have created a combobox and would like to place it in the header/footer of my document so it does not cover up data fields. See below:
[image]

Does anyone happen to know how to move it up there? I assume it will require VBA.

Here is a capture that demonstrates how far I can drag the box:
[image]

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Go to Developer tab >> Click on Design Mode. Then move the drop down. Please give more details on the the combo box is it Data validated or Active X combobox.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. The combobox cannot simply be moved outside of the constraints of the spreadsheet (added an image to show). The combo box has been made with Active X. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not letting you do that, you can't do that.

Comment: That's a bit aggravating but not the end of the world. I thought VB may be able to move it out of the way into a different region but never mind - It's not the end of the world! Thanks for the help.

Comment: HAHAHA... you can move the table below  the combo box, Also make sure that you change the setting of the combox to do not move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the `Worksheet` interface.

It exposes a `Shapes` collection, which is [ab]used to hold the ActiveX controls you put on it. As you probably already know, an ActiveX control's `Top` property can't be negative; if you programmatically make it negative, it's only going to be set to `0`. The ActiveX controls' setter for the `Top` property might look something like this:

```
Public Property Let Top(ByVal value As Long)
    If value < 0 Then value = 0
    mTop = value
End Property
```

Then there's a `PageSetup` property getter, that returns a `PageSetup` object - that's where you can configure, well, the *page setup*, including margins and custom headers. Notice the `PageSetup` interface doesn't expose anything like a `Shapes` collection: there's simply no support for ActiveX controls in the `PageSetup` object.

---

[As a comment correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549321/positioning-an-activex-combobox-in-an-excel-document-header#comment78059494_45549321), you can instead configure your `PageSetup` to have minimal margins and no content, and then do whatever you intended to put in the page header on the worksheet's client area instead - with the `PrintTitleRows` property you can have that "heading" appear at the top of every page, simulating a "page header" inside the client area where ActiveX controls are allowed to exist.

Comment: Ahha! I have an idea of how to work around this now. Thank you for taking your time to explain this to me, it's greatly appreciated